# eclipse -> Code Templates what are the variables available?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, uniqueidentifier

Found from [Change unhandled exception auto-generated catch code in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13275525/change-unhandled-exception-auto-generated-catch-code-in-eclipse) that we can use ${exception_var} and looking at http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fpreferences%2Fjava%2Fcodestyle%2Fref-preferences-code-templates.htm but which of these can I use in a try catch block to get a unique (to that class) name?

Reason : my developers (8) of them find it VERY difficult to edit these, and a lot of times code goes to production, where we have shut off log4j method name printing, so we see exception but not sure which line in a class its from.

Tried using

> ${index:newName(int)}

But says

> Variable 'newName' is unknown

Update : KVK comment helped, plus need to restart to see changes for try-catch at least

Comment: isn't ${enclosing_type} ${enclosing_method} solve your problem..

Comment: thanks KVK make that an answer and i will accept, Eclipse needed a restart to make it sticky, apply did not work.

Comment: Thank you tgkprog. Added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using

```
${enclosing_type}, ${enclosing_method}
```

Will solve your problem.