# Eclipse, change exception variable name in auto-generated code

Tags: java, eclipse

This is similar to [Change unhandled exception auto-generated catch code in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13275525/change-unhandled-exception-auto-generated-catch-code-in-eclipse)

which is about changing the code that Eclipse generates for the function 'sorround with try/catch block'.

In my case, I'd like to change the variable name that is used for the exception in such code (the one referred by ${exception_var} in the template). I don't like 'e', cause sometimes it clashes with already defined variables. `ex` and `try ( ex ) {...}` would be better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Eclipse Luna, go to Window > Preferences > Java > Code Style > Exception variable name in catch block.

Comment: Works with Eclipse 2021-06 (4.20.0)